# Reuse the C++ win forms project code in C# .net compact frame work?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-c++, compact-framework

I have created a project in Visual C++ win forms,

can anybody tell me

how to reuse the c++ win forms project in C#.Net? without using the Dll is possible??

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Add your C++ project to the solution containing C# project.
In the Visual Studio in the Solution Explorer panel right-click on the solution item, then Add -> Existing Project...

Comment: how to use the output of C++ project in C# project?

Comment: You can use all public classes and members of the C++ project in the C# project. Build the "Output" as you like.